# Get current route inside service provider in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

First of all, I have to tell that I am totally new on Laravel, so if you thing I am in the wrong way, please correct me.

Notice, that I have the Laravel 5.1 installed on my application.

I creating an application and I like to have my breadcrumbs inside an array, so I decide to create a Service Provider, and the code for the Service Provider is the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class BreadCrumbsServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    //  This will contain all the breadcrumb crumbs
    protected $crumbs = [];


    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->createBreadcrumb();
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(
            'crumbs',
            function() {
                return $this->crumbs;
            }
        );
    }

    protected function createBreadcrumb( ) {

        dd( Route::current() );

    }
}
```

So ,when I run my site, the `dd` returns just `null`. Can someone help me with this situation ?

Comment: Am not sure you are doing the write thing and using a service provider just for breadcrumbs is overkill

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Digitlimit, but do you have to sugest any other way ? As I already have describe, I am totally new on Laravel, so I don't know what's the best way for the breadcrumbs.

Comment: Its okay. you can look at this: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/breadcrumbs

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Inside your service provider class Route::Class won't work. Try these for

current request uri - `$this->app->request->getRequestUri()`

Current request method - `$this->app->request->getMethod()`